# Is there any possibility to color the html5 progress tag?

Tags: html, css

Is there any possibility to color the progress tag in css? I tried it. But only width and height is working. I want to skin the color of progression (inner color which shows the percentage of download). Is it possible?

Comment: If you have the same question and want to change appearance of HTML 5 `<progress>` tag, there is a good blog that describe it's how to very well [Here is The link](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2012/01/03/cross-browser-html5-progress-bars-in-depth/) this post is written a few month after this question. Enjoy!

Comment: This site helped me: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2012/01/03/cross-browser-html5-progress-bars-in-depth/

Comment: @priya Posted an answer that actually works, please test and accept or at the least comment.

Answer (score 48):

This is what you are looking for:

```
progress[value] {color:red} /* IE10 */
progress::-webkit-progress-bar-value {background:red}
progress::-webkit-progress-value {background:red}
progress::-moz-progress-bar {background:red}
```

It's working just fine on [Chrome](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Styling%20Form%20Controls) and [Firefox 6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/::-moz-progress-bar).
IE10 also supports the [::-ms-fill](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465757.aspx) pseudo-element.

Comment: @priya if that solves your problem you should click on the checkmark on the left.

Comment: @barraponto what *about* opera?

Comment: just a correction: you can't have them all special progress bar value setups in the same rule, because it breaks in some browsers (opera included). separate them into three different rules with the same body and it's good.

Comment: also webkit needs a special set for progress bar. so add: progress::-webkit-progress-bar { background-color: red }

Answer (score 3):

Currently no. The design/look-and-feel of the progress bar is currently defined by the browser and CSS cannot style the progress bar.

My current solution to this is to use multiple `div`s to style and show a progress bar, using CSS sprite images.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'll see what I can do to help  :/

I have looked at the default style (the css style of it) of the progress tag (using Google Chrome's Inspect element option) and what I found is the following (hope this helps):

```
1.  -webkit-appearance: progress-bar;
2.  background-attachment: scroll;
3.  background-clip: border-box;
4.  background-color: gray;
5.  background-image: none;
6.  background-origin: padding-box;
7.  border-bottom-color: black;
8.  border-bottom-style: none;
9.  border-bottom-width: 0px;
10. border-left-width: 0px;
11. border-right-width: 0px;
12. border-top-color: black;
13. border-top-style: none;
14. border-top-width: 0px;
15. display: inline-block;
16. font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
17. font-size: 16px;
18. height: 16px;
19. line-height: 16px;
20. margin-bottom: 0px;
21. margin-left: 0px;
22. margin-right: 0px;
23. margin-top: 0px;
24. outline-color: black;
25. outline-style: none;
26. outline-width: 0px;
27. padding-bottom: 0px;
28. padding-left: 0px;
29. padding-right: 0px;
30. padding-top: 0px;
31. position: static;
32. text-align: center;
33. vertical-align: -3px;
34. width: 160px;
Styles
________________________________________

element.style {}
Matched CSS Rules
user agent stylesheet

progress {
1.  -webkit-appearance: progress-bar;
2.  display: inline-block;
3.  height: 1em;
4.  width: 10em;
5.  vertical-align: -0.2em;
6.  background-color: gray;
}

Pseudo element
user agent stylesheet

progress::-webkit-progress-bar-value {
1.  -webkit-appearance: progress-bar;
2.  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **NOT** mix Mozilla and WebKit prefixes in the same selector, you **must** create completely separate rules for both rendering engines...

**CSS**

```
progress {background-color: #aaa !important;}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {background-color: #f0f !important;}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {background-color: #f0f !important;}
```

Tested in Firefox 31 and Chrome 37. Using #f0f because it *should* be easy to spot unless there are fundamental (and probably psychological) issues with the color scheme.