# How to style the value of a HTML5 progress bar with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, html, animation, styles

This is how I get the bar:

```
var bar = $('#progressbar');
```

I can style and animate it just fine, with either of:

```
bar.css(...)
bar.animate(...)
```

But how can I adjust the CSS for JUST the progress bar value element?

Like I can do in my styles.css file:

```
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    background:white;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Comment: How about using [JQuery UI progressbar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/) ? [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476573/jquery-ui-how-to-change-the-color-of-a-progressbar)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420609/how-to-style-the-value-of-a-html5-progress-bar-with-jquery

Comment: @cetver You put this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Vucko How ?(char lim)

Comment: @cetver The question you linked to is this one - you indicated it's a duplicate of itself... :)

Comment: @BrendanBullen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016011/is-there-any-possibility-to-color-the-html5-progress-tag ooops =)

Answer (score 0):

Just try it , Hope it helps

```
<progress id="progressBar" value="10" max="100" />

$('#click').click(function(){
    $('#progressBar').val(60);
})
```

For Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/fJxGG/196/

Comment: I don't have problems adjusting the value, but adjusting the CSS for the value element later.

Comment: It didn't help ;), I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @Microtechie the goal is too change progress bar css, not value

Answer (score 0):

if you want to chane css when value changes try:

```
var bar = $('#progressbar');
bar.change(function() {
    $(this).css('opacity',parseInt($(this).val())/100);
});
```

**EDIT** As far as I understood, that you need to style the strip, that presents the value, I have to edit my answer heavily. In fact, I didn't investigate a way to manipulate css pseudo-selectors  using jQuery and/or JavaScript, but there's the way to do it creating a stylesheet and changing it dinamically. Here it goes:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var style=document.createElement("style");
        var sheet = document.head.appendChild(style).sheet;
        var bar = $('#progressbar'); // your progress bar
// first of all, i create first rule
        sheet.insertRule('progress::-webkit-progress-value{ background-color: rgb('+bar.val()+','+bar.val()+','+bar.val()+');}');
        bar.change(function() {
// because here it throws an error if no 1st rule
            sheet.deleteRule(0);
            sheet.insertRule('progress::-webkit-progress-value{ background-color: rgb('+bar.val()+','+bar.val()+','+bar.val()+');}');        
        });

    });
```

I didn't test the code above (just changed it here), but it gives a basic representation what to do. [Here is](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/hfEpy/1/) working example with "plus" button, that increases value and changes `backgroung-color` of exactly value bar

I'm also dissapointed, that HTML5+JS is so poor in this, maybe later...

**EDIT2** actually `change()` for `<progress>` doesn't work in jQuery for some reason (it doesn't mean real javascript object doesn't have `onchange` property), so this example will not really work

check out [UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/hfEpy/2/)

Comment: again: I DON'T want to change the CSS of the progress bar itself, but of the `progress bar value element`

Comment: ok, I understood at last, not sure it's possible, but if `<progres>` is not mandatory, use `<div>` or `<span>` styled as you need - it can look as progress bar and it's 100 times easier

Comment: Yep, that's probably what i'm gonna end up doing. But damn, so much for html5 power ;-)