# How to apply same color for Progrss bar to make it to all browsers

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using html5 progress bar by default it's changing it's colors in different browsers I want to make it Unique for all browsers how can I could please tell me any one how can I achieve this?
thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any possibility to color the html5 progress tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016011/is-there-any-possibility-to-color-the-html5-progress-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply different colors for Progrss bar in html5

refer:
    http://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/